# phpinfo() difference between master and local value

Tags: php, virtual-hosts, safe-mode

I have a clean install of a CentOs with php 5.2.13.
In php.ini that is loaded and present in the header of phpinfo() I have

```
  safe_mode=off
```

in the phpinfo() information I have

```
// local value - safe_mode: On
// master value - safe_mode: off
```

the php file has only a phpinfo() function.
I am still looking for vhost file to see if any directives are there overwriting this, but still then any sugggestions?

Comment: Make sure that it is the same php.ini file you are modifying.

Comment: @sAc it is correct. I see other modifications

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found the problem/solution to be in the extra config file that is added in the vhosts folder.
The file is named httpd.include and it has this line

```
php_admin_flag safe_mode on
```

PS. I really hate when other systems create files on the fly like this, especially with values they want.

Answer (score 11):

"Master Value" (from php.ini) could be overridden with "Local Value" in **httpd.conf**, **.htaccess** or other Apache configuration with **php_value** directive.

Comment: Another reason that would cause error not displaying is the use of `@` in `@include` or `@require`. All included script will have error_reporting 0. Took me hours to find out.

Answer (score 10):

Look for "Additional ini files parsed" in phpinfo() output. This setting can also be changed in the Apache config (including .htaccess files).

Comment: the additional files are specific for the extra modules, and have not seen any global ini settings modified there.